# D3DXCreateTextureFromResource access violation

Tags: c++, directx, c++14, direct3d

D3DXCreateTextureFromResource is causing an access violation for a user sometimes. I cannot debug it because it never happens to me.

```
bool LoadTexture(LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9* texture, IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice, int resourceID)
{

    HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromResource(pDevice, dll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceID), texture);
    if (hr != D3D_OK)
    {
        char errorBuf[256];
        sprintf(errorBuf, "Error loading texture! Errorcode: %i", hr);
        MessageBoxA(NULL, errorBuf, "Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: They are seeing the message box?

Comment: @rogerdpack Nope the violation is from D3DXCreateTextureFromResource. It comes from nvd3dum.dll.

Comment: if it's in ``nvd3dum.dll``, then it's likely a driver bug. Also note that Direct3D 9 is legacy, ``D3DX9`` is deprecated, you should be using DirectX 11 [without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), etc. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). You also can try the Direct3D debug device, but there's no support for Direct3D 9 debugging for Windows 7 SP1 with DirectX 11.1 ([KB2670838](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/)) or later versions of Windows.

Comment: Where do you check that `pDevice` or `texture` pointers are valid?